# Python - Scrapy splash can't render this page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

https://www.miamidade.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=08/16/2018

This is the page that i'm trying to scrape. When i use SplashRequest to open it i get a different page with the same source.
Those are my settings for splas:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.99.100:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 
810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

My spider code:
    import scrapy
    from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

```
class RealForeclosure(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'realForeclosure'
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.miamidade.realforeclose.com/index.cfm? 
zaction=user&zmethod=calendar'
        ]

    def parse(self,response):
        link = 'https://www.miamidade.realforeclose.com/index.cfm? 
 zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE='
        date = response.xpath('//div[@tabindex="0"]/@dayid').extract()[10]
        yield SplashRequest(link+date, callback=self.auction)

    def auction(self, response):
        for i in response.css('.AUCTION_ITEM').extract():
            yield {'item':i}
```

Comment: Please post your spider code

Comment: i added the spider code

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of delay to allow Splash render result:

```
script1 = """
            function main(splash, args)
            assert (splash:go(args.url))
            assert (splash:wait(0.5))
            return {
                html = splash: html(),
                png = splash:png(),
                har = splash:har(),
            }
            end
          """

def parse(self,response):
    link = 'https://www.miamidade.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE='
    date = response.xpath('//div[@tabindex="0"]/@dayid').extract()[10]
    yield SplashRequest(
        link+date,
        callback=self.auction, 
        endpoint='execute',
        args={
            'html': 1,
            'lua_source': self.script1,
            'wait': 0.5,
        }
)
```